# Posting/retrieving photo-comments using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

When I use the Graph API to fetch a comment containing an image, the returned JSON contains no reference to it, e.g.

```
{
  "id": "10151452996201039_9302037", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Anton Raxacoricofallapatorius Dyudin", 
    "id": "1534947411"
  }, 
  "message": "", 
  "can_remove": true, 
  "created_time": "2013-06-20T06:47:41+0000", 
  "like_count": 0, 
  "user_likes": false
}
```

I am likewise lost as to what POST field can be used to embed a picture when commenting.
How can I achieve either of the above?

Comment: I also want to post photo comments through FB API but am lost. I don't think there's any way yet in the API to get or post them.

Answer (score 10):

Add `fields=attachment` to your query.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment

Comment: This would appear to be the case, however the API explorer grays out the choice with no explanation, and attempting the URL directly yields an "Unsupported get request" exception.

Comment: Graph api response does not seem to give the attachment field. Also the FQL query gives null for the field attachment. Any luck @Anton?

Comment: I have observed the same phenomenon: the field is null both through the FQL and the graph API, as well as in the graph explorer. Any idea anyone ?

Comment: Worked for me, too. Should be the accepted answer for anyone looking to get attachment data with their graph request.

Comment: I'm trying to get the feed comments. How to mention field parameter in me/feed api?

Answer (score 3):

It actually works when you use `fields=attachment`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POSTID_COMMENTID?fields=attachment&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more extensive query that return everythings and I mean everything including user id's, profile image (large version), comment related info as well and attachement info use this.

```
&fields=id,status_type,created_time,from{name,id,picture.width(400).height(400)},message,picture.width(400).height(400),link,icon,comments{comments{attachment,from{picture.width(400).height(400),name},id,message,created_time},from{picture.width(400).height(400),name},id,message,attachment,created_time}
```